# Should I return a reference or the hash?

Tags: perl, hash, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is returning a whole array from a Perl subroutine inefficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546175/is-returning-a-whole-array-from-a-perl-subroutine-inefficient)

I have this code

```
my $h = function($ref);

sub function {
    my $ref = shift @_;

    my %HoA = ();

    foreach my $key (keys %$ref) {
        $HoA{$key} = 1;
    }

    return \%HoA;

}
```

which returns a reference to `%HoA`.

In terms of performance and memory usage, is it best to return a reference or should I `return %HoA` ?

Comment: This is *not* the same question. A hash contains a bit more frozen *logic* than an array. If you "pour" it into a receiving hash it might (I don't know guts that well) have to re-hash the whole thing at the other end (although it could to a memcopy for efficiency--perlers are clever like that). So about the best thing I could say that it is algorithmically-simpler to return a reference to an assembled hash than to pass it as a list. (The "duplicate" references *arrays*.)

Answer (score 1):

If you return %HoA you return hash by its value, so it would be copied and takes additional memory. If you return it by reference it wouldn't be copied, so it's better in terms of performance and memory.

BTW, I think if you return %HoA then it will be destroyed by garbage collector because there wouldn't be any references on it.

Comment: Who is downvoting this without giving a comment why? It's not that comprehensive but not strictly incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

When providing the hash as plain hash all elements need to be copied. For really large hashes this might be a performance issue. When providing a hashref only the reference is copied. This generally faster.

Additionally you might find inspiration to improve your code in this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $ref = {
        foo => 23,
        bar => 42,
};

# do it with function
sub hash_to_1 {
        my $hash = shift;

        my %result;

        # list assignment like: (all hash elements) = ('1' as often as number of keys)
        @result{keys %$hash} = (1) x keys %$hash;

        return \%result;
}

# do it one line
my %new;
map { $new{$_} = 1} keys %$ref;
```

Comment: BTW If you do all this to have a boolean value (`1`/`0` meaning true/false) in the hash: Any other value that is not `0`, `undef` or `""` will evaluate to true. Thus it might not be actually necessary to get hash with all values 1.

Comment: Your two-line one-liner can be shortened to `my %new = map {$_ => 1} keys %$ref;`.